# Clone ParagraphProperties in Word using OpenXml SDK 2.0

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am programmly generating new paragraphs in Word document via Open XML SDK 2.0.
A have first paragraphs with properties, that i would like to append to all new generated paragraphs.

Somthing like this:

```
var _texts = new List<string>() { "Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 1", "Text 4"};
var sdtBlock = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<Paragraph>().First();
foreach (string _t in _texts)
{
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.Append(sdtBlock.ParagraphProperties);
    p.Append(new Run(new Text(_t)));
    sdtBlock.InsertAfterSelf<Paragraph>(p);
}
```

Executing this code throws an Exception: "Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree."
Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the `CloneNode()` method to make a copy of the instance of `ParagraphProperties` that you want to add to your new paragraph, e.g.

```
p.Append(sdtBlock.ParagraphProperties.CloneNode(true));
```

Otherwise, you'll get the exception you described (because you would be adding the original node in two different places in the same document, which is not allowed - and not what you were intending to do).